# I received an email from UKVI saying my application is not straightforward

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I received an email from UK Visas & Immigration regarding my application. I applied at VFS on 14th June and still have not received any update or passport collection email. It’s been 42 days. Do I still have any chance of receiving a visa? I’m confused about this email:

> Thank you for applying for a UK visa. Your visa application has been received and is under consideration.  We aim to process non settlement applications within 15 working days (unless you have opted for the Priority Visa service), and settlement applications within 120 working days.
>
> Unfortunately, the processing of your application has not been straightforward and we will be unable to decide your application within our customer service targets. We are continuing to work on your application and aim to make a decision as soon as possible.
>
> We will write to you again if there is any change to this. Please do not attend the Visa Application Centre until you have been advised that your application has been decided and that your passport is ready for collection.

Comment: We dont answer “what are my chances” questions because there are far too many variables.  The email simply is as it states - they typically aim to process applications within a published timeframe, but your application is more complex so they need more time and are telling you that.  UKVI get lots of “its been 15 days, wheres my visa?” queries where the applicant takes the published timeframe as a guarantee rather than an average, so this heads those queries off before they happen.

Comment: Thanks to your opinion @Moo

Comment: A friend of mine gave biometrics on 24 May and it took until 19 July for UKVI to advise him that a decision had been made and provide an appointment for 28 July for him to collect the decision letter. So 9 weeks *even for* a straightforward decision. What is it about your application that could have caused the response? Eg do you meet all the eligibility criteria? Do you have a good travel history, ties to home country etc etc

Comment: @Pavel, can I ask what your nationality is and the purpose of the visa?

Comment: I’m Bangladeshi nationality there’s a Reputed business man and do different type of business hotel business & vehicles import and wholesaler in my country also do some other small businesses I’m genuine traveler went many countries like japan Singapor Malaysia 4 time Dubai chaina 2 time Indonesia 2 time Soudi Arabia Thailand  India many time and Nepal etc I'm a married man I have couple of children and I’m financially sound and solvents. I’m travel lover my purpose of visit is tourism.

Answer (score 15):

> Do I still have any chance of receiving a visa?

Yes, you do.  You have not been rejected, therefore, you may still receive your visa — or not.  They just need more time to decide.

Comment: And this doesn't even necessarily mean there is a problem with the application. It could just be they are understaffed due to the combination of Covid, summer holidays, increased workload due to Brexit, increased workload due to Ukranian refugees, and everything else that is going on in the world right now. Heck, maybe they just ran out of ink for their stamps because of the global logistics crisis, who knows.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my observation of reports from forums of UK visa applicants, this message has been sent to a lot of recent applicants. Since the policy under which this notice is sent is internal Home Office policy we can only speculate about why this would be, but the suspicion is that due to an increasing backlog of visas, lately made worse by the Ukrainian refugee crisis, this notice is issued as an excuse for why the visa processing has not met the normal service standard, rather than due to any issue with the application itself.

Either way, there's nothing you can do about it. If your application had actually been considered already and found deficient, it would have been rejected. So we can conclude that you still have a 'chance' of receiving your visa.